# How can I Implement Dropout in SciKit-Learn?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, scikit-learn, mlp, dropout

I am working on an air-gapped PC and can only access the SciKit-Learn machine learning library. Unfortunately, its `MLPClassifier` doesn't include a Dropout hyperparameter, which severely limits the size of network I'm able to build.

How can I extend the Class and add Dropout to the algorithm/ model?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To implement this correctly you need to understand exactly how Dropout works, and where to change SciKit-Learn's `MLPClassifier` class to implement it. I'll start with an explanation of Dropout followed by the specifics of implementation. Skip to the end if you just want the code snippet.

## Understanding Dropout

The image below shows dropout visually, and is taken from the canonical [Dropout paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf?utm_content=buffer79b43&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer,) by Srivistava, and Hinton et al.

[image: Visual Demonstration of Dropout.]

The method is a form of regularisation that approximates averaging the predictions of hundreds to hundreds of thousands of smaller networks without massive computational overhead. For more details, read the paper above, for even more details read this [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/gal16.pdf) and this [paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2013/file/38db3aed920cf82ab059bfccbd02be6a-Paper.pdf). For a simple overview, watch Andrew Ng's [video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/deep-neural-network/dropout-regularization-eM33A) on the topic.

Put simply, Dropout switches off nodes in a Neural Net's layers, creating a series of smaller networks for your model to train on. It does this whilst preserving the overall architecture of your Neural Net. To create the smaller networks, each node is switched off randomly with a probability, $P$, a new hyperparameter, which makes the architecture of the smaller networks random. Training on varying, randomised architectures prevents nodes from Co-Adapting and overfitting the noise in your data.

Dropout is only applied during training, once the network is trained it uses its complete architecture to make predictions.

## Technical Details

From a technical point of view there are two things to consider, the Forward Pass, and Backpropagation.

### Forward Pass

In the forward pass the smaller network is created by building a Dropout Mask that sets the activation function of each switched off node to $0$, and multiplies the activation function of the remaining nodes by $1/P$.

Multiplying the remaining nodes' activation functions by $1/P$ is known as Inverted Dropout. This method ensures that the network sees the same scale of activations (nodes' output values) in training as it does in testing. Without this scaling, switching off nodes with a probability $P$ will scale the size of the activations by $(1-P)$. If this isn't counteracted, the network will be trained to make predictions on lower activation levels (node output values). This becomes an issue at test time, when the entire network is used, which makes the activations, on average, $1/P$ times larger, ruining the networks predictive ability.

Once the Dropout mask has been applied, the input is passed through the network normally.

### Backpropagation

To understand how backpropagation works with Dropout, it's worth adding an excerpt from the canonical [Dropout paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf?utm_content=buffer79b43&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer,).

[image: Excerpt on backpropagation from canonical Dropout paper.]

It states that backpropagation should be performed on the **thinned network only**, which means we have to prevent the algorithm updating the weights of switched off nodes' forwards and backwards connections as well as their biases (intercepts). This prevents nodes being trained on predictions that they contributed nothing towards.

## Implementing in SciKit-Learn

To implement this model, you need to understand SciKit-Learn's model design. This [webpage](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html) from SciKit-Learn goes over the development of new estimators. However, developing a whole new estimator is not necessary, instead we'll create a subclass of `MLPClassifier` called `MLPDropout`. I have assumed a base level of understanding in Python in Classes, Objects, Methods, Functions, etc. so if you don't understand Python I suggest you learn that first. I will post the entire code snippet at the end of this post, so skip to the end if you just want the answer. Keep reading if you're interested in the specific changes you have to make.

#### 1. Imports

To subclass `MLPClassifier` you will need the following imports, add them to the top of your file or Jupyter notebook.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network._stochastic_optimizers import AdamOptimizer
from sklearn.neural_network._base import ACTIVATIONS, DERIVATIVES, LOSS_FUNCTIONS
from sklearn.utils import shuffle, gen_batches, check_random_state, _safe_indexing
from sklearn.utils.extmath import safe_sparse_dot
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
```

#### 2. Adding a Dropout Hyperparameter

To control dropout in your new model you'll have to add a Dropout hyperparameter to the class's initialisation. This can be done by adding a new parameter to your subclass's initialisation function, which you can see at the bottom of `def __init__(...)` in the following code snippet.

```
class MLPDropout(MLPClassifier):
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        ... ( Parameters not included, see full code below.)
        dropout = None,
    ):
        '''
        Additional Parameters:
        ----------
        dropout : float in range (0, 1), default=None
            Dropout parameter for the model, defines the percentage of nodes
            to remove at each layer.
            
        '''
        self.dropout = dropout
        super().__init__( ... see parameters in full code below.)
```

The additional parameter is set as an internal attribute of the `MLPDropout` estimator, and `super().__init__(...)` calls `MLPClassifiers` initialisation function with the remaining parameters, as normal.

#### 3. Passing The Architecture (`layer_units`)

This next step is not strictly necessary, but seems to follow SciKit-Learn's design principles. `layer_units` is a variable instantiated by `MLPClassifer` that defines the node architecture of the Neural Net. To create the Dropout mask we need to pass this variable to the forward pass and backpropagation methods. Their are a couple of class methods that call forward pass and backpropagation, but, assuming you're using [Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf), the method we're interested in changing is `_fit_stochastic`, which is passed the `layer_units` parameter.

In `_fit_stochastic`'s call to `_backprop`, the function used by `MLPClassifer` to perform the forward pass and backpropagation, we add `layer_units` parameter.

```
# (DROPOUT ADDITION) layer_units passed forward to help build dropout mask.
batch_loss, coef_grads, intercept_grads = self._backprop(
    X_batch,
    y_batch,
    activations,
    layer_units,
    deltas,
    coef_grads,
    intercept_grads,
)
accumulated_loss += batch_loss * (
    batch_slice.stop - batch_slice.start
)
```

To see this in context, skip to the complete code snippet below. You also need to edit `_backprop` so that it can accept `layer_units`:

```
def _backprop(self, X, y, activations, layer_units, deltas, coef_grads, intercept_grads):
        """Compute the MLP loss function and its corresponding derivatives
        with respect to each parameter: weights and bias vectors.

        Parameters
        ----------
        ... (Parameters above cut off, see full code below)
             
        layer_units (DROPOUT ADDITION) : list, length = n_layers
            The layer units of the neural net, this is the shape of the
            Neural Net model. This is used to build the dropout mask.

        ... (Parameters below cut off, see full code below)
```

#### 4. Creating the Dropout Mask

To create the dropout mask you can use the `layer_units` variable, and the `self.dropout` hyperparameter to create a list of numpy arrays that mask the activation functions of the nodes.

```
# Create the Dropout Mask (DROPOUT ADDITION)
if self.dropout != None:
    if 0 < self.dropout < 1:
        keep_probability = 1 - self.dropout
        dropout_masks = [np.ones(layer_units[0])]

        # Create hidden Layer Dropout Masks
        for units in layer_units[1:-1]:
            # Create inverted Dropout Mask, check for random_state
            if self.random_state != None:
                layer_mask = (self._random_state.random(units) < keep_probability).astype(int) / keep_probability
            else:
                layer_mask = (np.random.rand(units) < keep_probability).astype(int) / keep_probability
            dropout_masks.append(layer_mask)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Dropout must be between zero and one. If Dropout=X then, 0 < X < 1.')
```

This creates a dropout mask that matches the size of each layer and adds it to a list. The first mask is for the input, which is set to all 1's in this implementation. Sometimes dropout is performed on the input nodes, but usually only in tasks where loss of a percentage of input data is minimally important. For example, image recognition. For tabular data this should be avoided.

#### 5. Applying the Mask in the Forward Pass

The `_forward_pass` method is called from inside of `_backprop` and must be updated to accept a `dropout_masks` variable. First within `_backprop`:

```
# Forward propagate
activations = self._forward_pass(activations, dropout_masks)
```

and then in the method definition:

```
def _forward_pass(self, activations, dropout_masks=None):
    """Perform a forward pass on the network by computing the values
    of the neurons in the hidden layers and the output layer.

    Parameters
    ----------
    activations : list, length = n_layers - 1
        The ith element of the list holds the values of the ith layer.
    dropout_mask : list, length = n_layers - 1
        The ith element of the list holds the dropout mask for the ith
        layer.
    """
```

`dropout_masks` has a default of `None` so that `MLPDropout` can be used exactly like `MLPClassifier` if you wish to have a dropout of zero. Assuming you are using Dropout, the `dropout_masks` are applied within `_forward_pass` by adding the following code to the forward pass for loop:

```
# Apply Dropout Mask (DROPOUT ADDITION)
if (i + 1) != (self.n_layers_ - 1) and dropout_masks != None:
    check1 = activations[i].copy()
    activations[i+1] = activations[i+1] * dropout_masks[i+1][None, :]
```

`_forward_pass`'s for loop iteratively assigns activations to a list. Multiplying the layer's activations by its corresponding mask makes the algorithm behave as if the masked nodes have been switched off.

#### 6. Applying the mask in Backpropagation

Finally, the mask must be applied again in backpropagation, as `MLPClassifier` includes a regularisation term that will update the weights of every node in a network regardless of their inclusion in the forward pass. The `_backprop` function calculates these gradients for you, and then passes them back to `_fit_stochastic`, which updates the model's coefficients (weights and biases). To follow the algorithm exactly, and **update the thinned network only**, you must zero out the coefficient gradients that correspond to switched off nodes. You can do this using the `dropout_masks` by adding the following code to the end of `_backprop`:

```
# Apply Dropout Masks to the Parameter Gradients (DROPOUT ADDITION)
if dropout_masks != None:
    for layer in range(len(coef_grads)-1):
        mask = (~(dropout_masks[layer+1] == 0)).astype(int)
        coef_grads[layer] = coef_grads[layer] * mask[None, :]
        coef_grads[layer+1] = (coef_grads[layer+1] * mask.reshape(-1, 1))
        intercept_grads[layer] = intercept_grads[layer] * mask
```

The first line, in the for loop, defines a new `mask` that no longer includes a scaling factor. The second line zeroes out the coefficient gradients for the weights connecting to switched off nodes in the current layer from the previous layer. The third line zeroes out the coefficient gradients of all connection weights passing from switched off nodes in the current layer to the next layer. The fourth line zeroes out the bias (SciKit-Learn calls it intercept) gradients of all switched off nodes in the current layer.

#### 7. Complete Code

At this stage, all the changes you need to make are complete. Please see the complete code for a new `MLPDropout` class below. Basic tests show that this model is marginally better than `MLPClassifier`.

```
# Creating a custom MLPDropout classifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network._stochastic_optimizers import AdamOptimizer
from sklearn.neural_network._base import ACTIVATIONS, DERIVATIVES, LOSS_FUNCTIONS
from sklearn.utils import shuffle, gen_batches, check_random_state, _safe_indexing
from sklearn.utils.extmath import safe_sparse_dot
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

class MLPDropout(MLPClassifier):
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),
        activation="relu",
        *,
        solver="adam",
        alpha=0.0001,
        batch_size="auto",
        learning_rate="constant",
        learning_rate_init=0.001,
        power_t=0.5,
        max_iter=200,
        shuffle=True,
        random_state=None,
        tol=1e-4,
        verbose=False,
        warm_start=False,
        momentum=0.9,
        nesterovs_momentum=True,
        early_stopping=False,
        validation_fraction=0.1,
        beta_1=0.9,
        beta_2=0.999,
        epsilon=1e-8,
        n_iter_no_change=10,
        max_fun=15000,
        dropout = None,
    ):
        '''
        Additional Parameters:
        ----------
        dropout : float in range (0, 1), default=None
            Dropout parameter for the model, defines the percentage of nodes
            to remove at each layer.
            
        '''
        self.dropout = dropout
        super().__init__(
            hidden_layer_sizes=hidden_layer_sizes,
            activation=activation,
            solver=solver,
            alpha=alpha,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            learning_rate=learning_rate,
            learning_rate_init=learning_rate_init,
            power_t=power_t,
            max_iter=max_iter,
            shuffle=shuffle,
            random_state=random_state,
            tol=tol,
            verbose=verbose,
            warm_start=warm_start,
            momentum=momentum,
            nesterovs_momentum=nesterovs_momentum,
            early_stopping=early_stopping,
            validation_fraction=validation_fraction,
            beta_1=beta_1,
            beta_2=beta_2,
            epsilon=epsilon,
            n_iter_no_change=n_iter_no_change,
            max_fun=max_fun,
        )
    
    def _fit_stochastic(
        self,
        X,
        y,
        activations,
        deltas,
        coef_grads,
        intercept_grads,
        layer_units,
        incremental,
    ):
        params = self.coefs_ + self.intercepts_
        if not incremental or not hasattr(self, "_optimizer"):
            if self.solver == "sgd":
                self._optimizer = SGDOptimizer(
                    params,
                    self.learning_rate_init,
                    self.learning_rate,
                    self.momentum,
                    self.nesterovs_momentum,
                    self.power_t,
                )
            elif self.solver == "adam":
                self._optimizer = AdamOptimizer(
                    params,
                    self.learning_rate_init,
                    self.beta_1,
                    self.beta_2,
                    self.epsilon,
                )

        # early_stopping in partial_fit doesn't make sense
        early_stopping = self.early_stopping and not incremental
        if early_stopping:
            # don't stratify in multilabel classification
            should_stratify = is_classifier(self) and self.n_outputs_ == 1
            stratify = y if should_stratify else None
            X, X_val, y, y_val = train_test_split(
                X,
                y,
                random_state=self._random_state,
                test_size=self.validation_fraction,
                stratify=stratify,
            )
            if is_classifier(self):
                y_val = self._label_binarizer.inverse_transform(y_val)
        else:
            X_val = None
            y_val = None

        n_samples = X.shape[0]
        sample_idx = np.arange(n_samples, dtype=int)

        if self.batch_size == "auto":
            batch_size = min(200, n_samples)
        else:
            if self.batch_size < 1 or self.batch_size > n_samples:
                warnings.warn(
                    "Got `batch_size` less than 1 or larger than "
                    "sample size. It is going to be clipped"
                )
            batch_size = np.clip(self.batch_size, 1, n_samples)

        try:
            for it in range(self.max_iter):
                if self.shuffle:
                    # Only shuffle the sample indices instead of X and y to
                    # reduce the memory footprint. These indices will be used
                    # to slice the X and y.
                    sample_idx = shuffle(sample_idx, random_state=self._random_state)

                accumulated_loss = 0.0
                for batch_slice in gen_batches(n_samples, batch_size):
                    if self.shuffle:
                        X_batch = _safe_indexing(X, sample_idx[batch_slice])
                        y_batch = y[sample_idx[batch_slice]]
                    else:
                        X_batch = X[batch_slice]
                        y_batch = y[batch_slice]
                    
                    activations[0] = X_batch
                    # (DROPOUT ADDITION) layer_units passed forward to help build dropout mask.
                    batch_loss, coef_grads, intercept_grads = self._backprop(
                        X_batch,
                        y_batch,
                        activations,
                        layer_units,
                        deltas,
                        coef_grads,
                        intercept_grads,
                    )
                    accumulated_loss += batch_loss * (
                        batch_slice.stop - batch_slice.start
                    )

                    # update weights
                    grads = coef_grads + intercept_grads
                    self._optimizer.update_params(params, grads)

                self.n_iter_ += 1
                self.loss_ = accumulated_loss / X.shape[0]

                self.t_ += n_samples
                self.loss_curve_.append(self.loss_)
                if self.verbose:
                    print("Iteration %d, loss = %.8f" % (self.n_iter_, self.loss_))

                # update no_improvement_count based on training loss or
                # validation score according to early_stopping
                self._update_no_improvement_count(early_stopping, X_val, y_val)

                # for learning rate that needs to be updated at iteration end
                self._optimizer.iteration_ends(self.t_)

                if self._no_improvement_count > self.n_iter_no_change:
                    # not better than last `n_iter_no_change` iterations by tol
                    # stop or decrease learning rate
                    if early_stopping:
                        msg = (
                            "Validation score did not improve more than "
                            "tol=%f for %d consecutive epochs."
                            % (self.tol, self.n_iter_no_change)
                        )
                    else:
                        msg = (
                            "Training loss did not improve more than tol=%f"
                            " for %d consecutive epochs."
                            % (self.tol, self.n_iter_no_change)
                        )

                    is_stopping = self._optimizer.trigger_stopping(msg, self.verbose)
                    if is_stopping:
                        break
                    else:
                        self._no_improvement_count = 0

                if incremental:
                    break

                if self.n_iter_ == self.max_iter:
                    warnings.warn(
                        "Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (%d) "
                        "reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet."
                        % self.max_iter,
                        ConvergenceWarning,
                    )
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            warnings.warn("Training interrupted by user.")

        if early_stopping:
            # restore best weights
            self.coefs_ = self._best_coefs
            self.intercepts_ = self._best_intercepts
    
    def _backprop(self, X, y, activations, layer_units, deltas, coef_grads, intercept_grads):
        """Compute the MLP loss function and its corresponding derivatives
        with respect to each parameter: weights and bias vectors.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            The input data.

        y : ndarray of shape (n_samples,)
            The target values.

        activations : list, length = n_layers - 1
            The ith element of the list holds the values of the ith layer.
             
        layer_units (DROPOUT ADDITION) : list, length = n_layers
            The layer units of the neural net, this is the shape of the
            Neural Net model. This is used to build the dropout mask.

        deltas : list, length = n_layers - 1
            The ith element of the list holds the difference between the
            activations of the i + 1 layer and the backpropagated error.
            More specifically, deltas are gradients of loss with respect to z
            in each layer, where z = wx + b is the value of a particular layer
            before passing through the activation function

        coef_grads : list, length = n_layers - 1
            The ith element contains the amount of change used to update the
            coefficient parameters of the ith layer in an iteration.

        intercept_grads : list, length = n_layers - 1
            The ith element contains the amount of change used to update the
            intercept parameters of the ith layer in an iteration.

        Returns
        -------
        loss : float
        coef_grads : list, length = n_layers - 1
        intercept_grads : list, length = n_layers - 1
        """
        n_samples = X.shape[0]
        dropout_masks = None
        
        # Create the Dropout Mask (DROPOUT ADDITION)
        if self.dropout != None:
            if 0 < self.dropout < 1:
                keep_probability = 1 - self.dropout
                dropout_masks = [np.ones(layer_units[0])]
                
                # Create hidden Layer Dropout Masks
                for units in layer_units[1:-1]:
                    # Create inverted Dropout Mask, check for random_state
                    if self.random_state != None:
                        layer_mask = (self._random_state.random(units) < keep_probability).astype(int) / keep_probability
                    else:
                        layer_mask = (np.random.rand(units) < keep_probability).astype(int) / keep_probability
                    dropout_masks.append(layer_mask)
            else:
                raise ValueError('Dropout must be between zero and one. If Dropout=X then, 0 < X < 1.')
        
        # Forward propagate
        # Added dropout_makss to _forward_pass call (DROPOUT ADDITION)
        activations = self._forward_pass(activations, dropout_masks)
        
        # Get loss
        loss_func_name = self.loss
        if loss_func_name == "log_loss" and self.out_activation_ == "logistic":
            loss_func_name = "binary_log_loss"
        loss = LOSS_FUNCTIONS[loss_func_name](y, activations[-1])
        # Add L2 regularization term to loss
        values = 0
        for s in self.coefs_:
            s = s.ravel()
            values += np.dot(s, s)
        loss += (0.5 * self.alpha) * values / n_samples

        # Backward propagate
        last = self.n_layers_ - 2

        # The calculation of delta[last] here works with following
        # combinations of output activation and loss function:
        # sigmoid and binary cross entropy, softmax and categorical cross
        # entropy, and identity with squared loss
        deltas[last] = activations[-1] - y
        
        # Compute gradient for the last layer
        self._compute_loss_grad(
            last, n_samples, activations, deltas, coef_grads, intercept_grads
        )

        inplace_derivative = DERIVATIVES[self.activation]
        # Iterate over the hidden layers
        for i in range(self.n_layers_ - 2, 0, -1):
            deltas[i - 1] = safe_sparse_dot(deltas[i], self.coefs_[i].T)
            inplace_derivative(activations[i], deltas[i - 1])
            
            self._compute_loss_grad(
                i - 1, n_samples, activations, deltas, coef_grads, intercept_grads
            )
        
        # Apply Dropout Masks to the Parameter Gradients (DROPOUT ADDITION)
        if dropout_masks != None:
            for layer in range(len(coef_grads)-1):
                mask = (~(dropout_masks[layer+1] == 0)).astype(int)
                coef_grads[layer] = coef_grads[layer] * mask[None, :]
                coef_grads[layer+1] = (coef_grads[layer+1] * mask.reshape(-1, 1))
                intercept_grads[layer] = intercept_grads[layer] * mask
        
        return loss, coef_grads, intercept_grads
    
    def _forward_pass(self, activations, dropout_masks=None):
        """Perform a forward pass on the network by computing the values
        of the neurons in the hidden layers and the output layer.

        Parameters
        ----------
        activations : list, length = n_layers - 1
            The ith element of the list holds the values of the ith layer.
        dropout_mask : list, length = n_layers - 1
            The ith element of the list holds the dropout mask for the ith
            layer.
        """
        hidden_activation = ACTIVATIONS[self.activation]
        # Iterate over the hidden layers
        for i in range(self.n_layers_ - 1):
            activations[i + 1] = safe_sparse_dot(activations[i], self.coefs_[i])
            activations[i + 1] += self.intercepts_[i]
            
            # For the hidden layers
            if (i + 1) != (self.n_layers_ - 1):
                hidden_activation(activations[i + 1])
            
            # Apply Dropout Mask (DROPOUT ADDITION)
            if (i + 1) != (self.n_layers_ - 1) and dropout_masks != None:
                check1 = activations[i].copy()
                activations[i+1] = activations[i+1] * dropout_masks[i+1][None, :]

        # For the last layer
        output_activation = ACTIVATIONS[self.out_activation_]
        output_activation(activations[i + 1])
        return activations
```

Comment: I enjoyed reading your answer. It has the correct balance between theory and code. I hope you can continue to share your knowledge and correct what people like the top 1 contributor in this network have done with his opinion-based, not supported answers. (@Erwan)

Comment: This should be added to SKLearn officially, thank you so much for laying it all out so thoroughly!

Comment: That's great ! You should make a pull request for this new feature.